# Format of a jump table

Tags: assembly, gdb, jump-table

I am reading an example on a course about jump tables. They call `gdb x/8g 0x123456`

The resulting output looks like:

```
0x123456    0x000000000000134234    0x0000000000005f424
0x123487    0x0000000000001dd1ac    0x000000000000ef327
```

I thought a jump table maps an address to the address of the code it should execute. Why then are there 3 columns (shouldn't it be 2?).

Comment: Have you read a gdb manual to see what `x` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why then are there 3 columns (shouldn't it be 2?)

You didn't paste the real GDB output, which looked something like:

```
0x123450    0x000000000000134234    0x0000000000005f424
0x123460    0x0000000000001dd1ac    0x000000000000ef327
```

(the first column is different). In programming, details *matter*.

If you make the terminal narrower, then you'll get 2 columns, like this:

```
0x123450    0x000000000000134234
0x123458    0x0000000000005f424
0x123460    0x0000000000001dd1ac
0x123468    0x000000000000ef327
```

As KerrekSB suggested, read the GDB manual to understand what `x` does. Hint: the first column doesn't really matter -- it's where the table itself is stored.